# Sharing state between React and Angular applications in the same web browser

Tags: reactjs, angular, redux, state-management

I have two applications running in the same web browser, one built with React.js and the other with Angular. Both applications are integrated with Redux for state management. Now, I need to display the state from the React.js application in the Angular application and vice versa.

Is there a recommended approach or best practice for sharing state between these two frameworks? I've considered using browser events, but I'm not sure if that's the most efficient or reliable solution. Are there any libraries or techniques specifically designed for this kind of cross-framework state sharing?

I appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to achieve this integration successfully. Thank you!

Comment: It does not matter if you have Angular and React or React and React application the code will be the same. The problem you have is that you want to share state between two different applications in different tabs. So you need to implement code that will propagate dispatch events from one application to the other. You can use Redux Middleware and native BroadcastChannel.